# display number of <td> columns based on the attribute value using xslt

Tags: xslt

I want to display <td> columns based on the attribute value of **count** using **for-each** loop. Can someone help me to achieve it ? I am new to XSLT development.

XML node:
<row count="72">

Edit: count - is referred here for **Number of Columns in the row**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?  It's _much_ easier in 2.0.

Comment: its 1.0, appreciate if you can post both solutions.Thanks

Comment: Your problem is not clear - at least to me: Do you want to display 72 colums or does the example show one column with the value of "72" to be displayed? Why is the element named row?

Comment: @Andreas : I want to display 72 columns since the count=72, using for-each loop I want to iterate from 1 till 72.

Comment: count is referred to Number of Columns in the row

Comment: Haven't been in some time, but I see now the question is clear it's been answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0 you can use the "to" operator, and simply say

```
<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:variable name="theRow" select="." />
  <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="1 to @count">
      <td><!-- insert cell contents here --></td>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

Within the `for-each`, `.` will be the current *number*, so if you need access to the `row` element you need to save it in a variable.

Comment: Unfortunately the question is about XSLT 1.0, +1 nevertheless.

Comment: Indeed, I only included this for completeness because @user2218497 asked for "both solutions" - your answer should be the accepted one.

Comment: I always like when the OP doesn't descend to commenting on any answer they get. Classical indicator that this was nothing but a Mechanical Turk question. :-/

Answer (score 1):

If your counts are not in the thousands this can be done by simple recursion. Iteration is impossible because there are no modifiable variables in XSLT.

```
<xsl:template match="row[@count &gt; 0]">
  <xsl:call-template name="new-td">
    <xsl:with-param name="count" select="@count" />
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="new-td">
  <xsl:param name="count" select="0" />

  <xsl:if test="$count">
    <!-- create current cell -->
    <td>
      <!-- contents... -->
    </td>

    <!-- recursive step: create next cell -->
    <xsl:call-template name="new-td">
      <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$count - 1" />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Depending on how smart your XSLT processor is it will optimize this into an iterative loop behind the scenes so that stack overflow errors are unlikely to occur, regardless of how high `$count` is. Try with a really high number to find out how your XSLT processor reacts.

Recommended reading: [Use recursion effectively in XSL](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xslrecur/) on IBM DeveloperWorks, especially the section *"Recursion Example 2: Iterating on a number"*.